# Regular Expression match character OR number

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get parts of a string separated by the type (number or character)

**Simplified** initial situation:

```
var content = 'foo123bar456';
```

Desired result:

```
result = ['foo', 123, 'bar', 456];
```

This is what I have so far to match the first "foo"

```
^(([a-z])|([0-9]))+
```

I thought this would match either characters [a-z]+ OR numbers [0-9]+  (which would match 'foo' in this case) but unfortunately it allows both (characters AND numbers) at the same time.

If it would match only characters with the same type I could just add "{1,}" to my regex in order to match all occurrences of the pattern and the world would be a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct regex will be:

```
([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)
```

Explanation of the regex is:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: Indeed. This was an impressively fast answer that will save my day! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `g` modifier as well for global match

```
[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g
```